# How to convert 08:48 PM time into SQL unixtime?

Tags: java

How do I convert 08:48 PM formatted string into SQL Unixtime?

Java 1.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you still want today's date, try

```
String today = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd ").format(new Date());
long timestamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm a").parse(today + "08:48 PM").getTime() / 1000;
```

Answer (score 5):

You need [`java.text.SimpleDateFormat`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) with the `hh:mm a` pattern (0-12 hours, minutes, AM/PM marker). Click the link to see the Javadoc with detailed pattern explanations.

```
String time = "08:48 PM";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm a").parse(time);
long timestampMillis = date.getTime();
long unixTimestamp = timestampMillis / 1000;
```

---

If you *actually* want to store this in a SQL TIME/TIMESTAMP/DATETIME field with help of [JDBC](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/jdbc/index.html), then wrap it in a  [`java.sql.Time`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) and use [`PreparedStatement#setTime()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setTime%28int,%20java.sql.Time%29) to save it.

```
Time time = new Time(timestampMillis); // Yes, with millis!
preparedStatement.setTime(1, time);
// ...
```